# How to run c# app having dll files on linux

Tags: c#

My c# apps developed on windows run nicely on ubuntu, but the ones having dll files don't. Is there a work around or i have to recompile the code on linux

Comment: Some part of error:'                                  System.DllNotFoundException: ole32.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.__ComObject:CoCreateInstance (System.Guid,intptr,uint,System.Guid,intptr&)'

Comment: the dll file used is Interop.SpeechLib.dll.

Answer (score 3):

`Interop.SpeechLib.dll` is part of Microsoft's Speech API (SAPI).

That doesn't exist on Linux, so you'll have to find an alternative API to call there.

You won't necessarily have to maintain two separate code bases, though. You could execute a run-time check for the host platform/environment, and call the appropriate API for that environment.